# Unable to open file from python list

Tags: python, file-io

I have a python list that contains the following path

```
\\\\serverName\\wwwroot\\Public\\Metadata\\Open Spaces.xml
```

When I try and go through the list and open the file

```
for xml in xmlPathList:
    openFile = open(xml, 'r')
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 2, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u' \\\\serverName\\wwwroot\\Public\\Metadata\\Open Spaces.xml'
```

I have tried the following code

```
d = open("\\\\serverName\\wwwroot\\Public\\Metadata\\Open Spaces.xml", 'r')
```

and that seems to work perfectly, the only difference I can see is the quotes that are passed in.. single quotes vs double quotes.

Has anyone got any idea of why this isn't working, or a way to pass in the pathname with a double quote

Comment: Can you confirm that the two strings are equivalent? I suspect otherwise. Also, you don't need the second parameter 'r' in open. With just xml passed in, read is implied.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a space character at the beginning of the failing name!

Comment: I see a *space* at the start of the string in your error message. I am also damn sure my edit didn't introduce that space, it was present in your first revision. Is that error message accurate?

Comment: @CodePainters: That should make no difference, Python and Windows support Unicode path names *just fine*. In fact, I'd go so far as *recommending* you use Unicode path names on Windows.

Comment: Seems like file name in the list has a leading space?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, that was my blind guess, I already realized it shouldn't matter. And then I saw the leading space... :)

Comment: yes you are correct there is a space at the start with I did not see, which is the reason why it couldn't find the file... thanks for your help!!!! (lesson learnt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message indicates you have a space in the file name:

```
u' \\\\serverName\\wwwroot\\Public\\Metadata\\Open Spaces.xml'
  ^
  Here
```

One option is to clean the python list manually of extra spaces.

Another option is to do this programmatically using [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
xmlPathList = [u' \\\\serverName\\wwwroot\\Public\\Metadata\\Open Spaces.xml']
for xml in xmlPathList:
    openFile = open(xml.strip(), 'r')
```